# Ineffective setting: Wi-Fi non-persistent MAC randomization

Tags: wi-fi, mac-address

Sometimes I want to use a certain hotspot providing free 1-hour Wi-Fi multiple times, but the provider remembers the MAC address of my smartphone.

I enabled the developer setting "Wi-Fi non-persistent MAC randomization" and enabled the advanced connection option "Use randomized MAC". However, no matter how many times I click "Forget" on the connection next time the phone assigns the same MAC address.

So currently I can only connect two times: with the "randomized" address and then switch to the physical address.

The phone is Pixel 3 XL, Android 12

Answer (score 0):

It seens that the MAC address is assigned each time you activate Wifi. So turn off wifi  and then turn it on again.

More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421899/does-mac-address-changes-over-time-in-android)